# Reactivating Xubuntu after locking the screen doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, screen

Bonjour,

I have a problem with my laptop at work since monday. Everytime when lock the pc the screen turns black and it's not possible for me to login again. The problem behind this is that I have to lock my pc everytime when I leave it.

I tried things like `xset -dpms` but this didn't help.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem? Even our system integrators don't have an idea.

My laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad W510 with Xubuntu 16.04 as operating system.

Please keep your answers easy, because I'm not a Linux specialist.

Thanks

P.S.: Tell me if you need more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonjour,

after a few days with more and more problems I solved the problem. It was an issue with the used Kernel **4.13.0**. I started using an older kernel **4.10.0** and this solved my problem.